# kASLR still on after adding nokaslr parameter

Tags: grub2

I tried to turn off flag `CONFIG_RANDOMIZE_BASE` which is in `/boot/config-....`. Now, I follow the command mentioned in [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/397939/turning-off-kaslr-to-debug-linux-kernel-using-qemu-and-gdb) and it seems what I did is right, I'm surely `nokalsr` was added:

```
$ grep quiet /etc/default/grub
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet nokaslr splash"
```

But when I tried to check flag in `/boot/config-....`:

```
$ cat /boot/config-`uname -r` | grep "CONFIG_RANDOMIZE_BASE"
CONFIG_RANDOMIZE_BASE=y
```

My question is why `CONFIG_RANDOMIZE_BASE` still on?

Answer (score 0):

@Steven the config-xxx fragments under the /boot are actually the configurations the vmlinuz-xxx under the same /boot was built with. You are mixing up the idea of build-time vs run-time configurations.

So, the kernel-xxx was built (build-time) with CONFIG_RANDOMIZE_BASE enabled but you can disable it at run-time using the kernel bootargs as is being done in the post you linked to.